# Regex - Match two words or one word, but give preference to two words

Tags: java, python, regex

I have the following scenario where I have a set of phrases, some are couple of words, some are words alone, I'd like to match all this phrases but with my current approach I end up matching single words

For Example:

Things I could match:

- sunny day
- sunny valley
- day

Regex: `(sunny( )day|sunny( )valley|day)`

Sentence: today is a sunny day

here, I hope that "sunny day" is matched however, my regex always matches "day", there might be other sentences that contain day alone that I want to match.

Does anyone know how to design a regex that accomplish this task?

Comment: You have capturing groups for spaces. Is it on purpose?

Comment: @emartinelli not on purpose, I just wanted to specify a space right there without getting mixed results, maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: You can use '\s' to represent a space. But even using a "real space", you don't need parentheses, because in this case it will only generate additional matches. E.g.: using @stribizhev answer and your input, 'sunny day' and a space will be matched. To not match this additional space, use '\b(sunny\sday|sunny\svalley|day)\b' [(demo)](https://regex101.com/r/iS9bY7/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches "day" inside "today" as it is the leftmost (first) "day" substring in the input string.

Use word boundaries to match whole words only:

```
\b(sunny( )day|sunny( )valley|day)\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR3qK5/1)

Comment: that was it, I was actually using \b in my code generated regex (\bsunny( )day\b|\bday\b) but I was not getting the desired outcome, with your suggestion outside of the group, now I get the longest match, thanks! will mark as the right answer in 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

To not generate additional matches of spaces. Following OP's comment. I suggest this Regex:

`\b(sunny\sday|sunny\svalley|day)\b` [(demo)](https://regex101.com/r/iS9bY7/1)

---

Ps.:

`\s` is for spaces

Parentheses are not useful, because matching of spaces is not desirable in this case.